# Visiting or visit or are visiting after while in this example

Tags: gerunds

Would it be possible for us to leave our luggage at the apartmen**t while  visiting ,are visiting or visit** the castle.

I think visiting or visit are the best here because visit implies a continuous action so there is no need of continuous .

Comment: "Luggage" is uncountable.

Answer (score 1):

**While we are visiting** or **while we visit** are both acceptable. It's also possible to use **while visiting**, in which case the 'we are' is implied.

The verb *to visit* doesn't necessarily imply a continuing action.

Comment: While talking about _"we are" being implied_ may be useful as a teaching device, I don't think it stands up to analysis. This is a particpial construction, not a "present continuous", as it can be used with verbs which rarely or never take that construction: _while knowing_, _while hating_, _while forgetting_.

Answer (score 0):

Both "visiting" and "we visit" can be used here

The appropriate sentence to be used can be 4 cases:

> Would it be possible for us to leave our luggage at the apartment **while** visiting the castle?

> Would it be possible for us to leave our luggage at the apartment **while** we visit the castle?

These ^ are a bit vague, due to it mentioning that we will leave our luggages "while" visiting the castle, which physically is impossible, as you cannot leave your luggage at your apartment *when* you are at the castle. But it is still useable definitely

or

> Would it be possible for us to leave our luggage at the apartment **when** visiting the castle?

> Would it be possible for us to leave our luggage at the apartment **when** we visit the castle?

This sentence is better but also have nearly the same meaning as the above

or

> Would it be possible for us to leave our luggags at the apartment **before** visiting the castle?

> Would it be possible for us to leave our luggage at the apartment **before** we visit the castle?

This is the best option as it is clear that we will leave the luggage before you visit the castle, the most logical as well.

Comment: You really should correct the erroneous pluralisation of "luggages". To native speakers, it just looks off-puttingly awful (and to my browser's spell-checker, which underlines in red where I just wrote it in my comment here! :).

Comment: do I make it "luggage's" @FumbleFingers?

Comment: Certainly not! _Luggage_ is uncountable (as I forgot to mention in my answer earlier).

Comment: Can I use during 'Can we leave our luggage at the apartment during the visit of the castle 'Is it more logical to use during

Comment: Yes you can use during, both before and during are equally logical IMO @user5577